# How to add items to an MFC CListCtrl object so their icons appear in top-to-bottom sequence?

Tags: mfc, sequences, clistctrl

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2008 v 3.5 SP1 (with Feature Pack).

After adding items to an MFC `CListCtrl` object via `InsertItem()`, their icons appear in reverse row order, but correct column order, in most of the view modes.
I'm not using "report" (`LV_VIEW_DETAILS`) mode, so the rows and columns I mention refer to how the icons are sequenced within a grid or layout.

I add them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item_count; ++i)
    list_ctrl.InsertItem (i, item_arr[i].text, i);
```

and would like them to appear like this:

```
icon 0
icon 1
icon 2
:
icon N-2
icon N-1
```

(where icon # matches its item # and N is `item_count`).

However, in "large icon", "small icon" and "tile" (`LV_VIEW_ICON`, `LV_VIEW_SMALLICON`, `LV_VIEW_TILE`) modes, they appear like this:

```
icon N-1
icon N-2
:
icon 2
icon 1
icon 0
```

They only appear in correct sequence in "list" (`LV_VIEW_LIST`) mode, but then they arrange and scroll horizontally:

```
icon 0  icon 1  icon 2  ..  icon N-2  icon N-1
```

(Whether they appear all in a single row/column is merely a function of the relative size/dimension of the icons and the control.)
It seems I can have vertical orientation but reverse order, or correct order but wrong orientation!

How do I get things the way I want? I've seen nothing in the docs or in forums about this -- only about sorting items by text (which I don't want) or sorting the order of columns in details/report mode (which I don't want).

Comment: @Jonathan, Bart or anyone:
Why reformat so much of my prose as code?
I can see the point of doing so with names/types that can/do appear in code, but words like "relative size/dimension" or "property" ... ?

Comment: Sorry - I improved on some changes made by [Joy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/344304/joy), but I concentrated on the 'i' to 'I' mapping that was omitted, and noted that the code as code changes were an improvement.  I agree that 'relative size/dimension' etc in the running text would be better left as plain text; I should have unfixed those, and I apologize for not being ruthless enough on the re-edit. You could edit it to suit yourself, but remember that if you had gotten the presentation 'better' in the first place, no edit would have been needed at all. You can always edit your question.

Comment: I see that Bart removed a smiley and some ellipsis; Joy again did the emphasis.  His changes were approved by 'people'.  In the case of the question, I think I marked Joy's changes as helpful.  I would probably have left the 'answer' with: _I needed to change the `OwnerDrawFixed` property back to `False`!_ which doesn't emphasize property.  And I would probably had added 'it' to: _Now it works as expected._ But in general, smileys are not used much on SO, and on the whole that is a good thing.  (Comment again if you want me to do the cleanup for you; I will, since I contributed to the mess.)

Comment: @Jonathan et al. Thanks for the improvements (and explanation re good style). I don't mean to be picky, but you mention Joy's edits but i see no formal reference to Joy. Also, i'm not sure what you mean by "were approved by 'people'". Is 'people' another user, the users in general, ...?

Comment: Go to the revisions (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10726216/revisions), and look at revision 2.  You can also do that by clicking on the time by the 'edited 1 hour ago' (as I type) part at the bottom of the question, next to your 'asked' information.  "Approved by people" means that the edits were proposed by someone without the reputation that allows them to edit anything.  Such edits are scrutinized by those who can do the editing, and (normally) two people approve an edit before it is accepted.  So, Joy's changes were approved by two people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too much time we finally figured it out:
I needed to change the `OwnerDrawFixed` property (back) to `False`!
Now it works as expected.